# Is there a way to embed this discord message discord bot python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

i have been struggling to embed this message , its currently getting the images from the path of the python project and sending them , but i wanted to embed them like this:

Title being Image:
Description being Enjoy!
And the coloured side bar to be red

[Example of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0w4K.png)

current code :

```
@client.command()
async def image(channel):
    file = random.choice(files)
    await channel.send(file=discord.File(file))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about embeds before simply asking what to do without any effort.

```py
@client.command()
async def image(channel):
    file = random.choice(files)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="Enjoy!", color=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_image(url=file)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```